# Post a comment on facebook with Jodd a httpclient

Tags: java, facebook, http, jodd

How can I post a comment on my profile with `Jodd` and `httpclient` once logged in?

```
final HttpBrowser browser = new HttpBrowser();

HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.get("www.facebook.com");
browser.sendRequest(request);

String page = browser.getPage();
Jerry doc = Jerry.jerry(page);

// process login form
doc.form("#login_form", new JerryFormHandler() {
    public void onForm(Jerry form, Map<String, String[]> parameters) {

        String formAction = form.attr("action");
        HttpRequest loginRequest = HttpRequest.post(formAction);

        for (Map.Entry<String, String[]> entry : parameters.entrySet()) {
            String[] values = entry.getValue();
            String name = entry.getKey();

            for (String value : values) {
                loginRequest.form(name, value);
            }
        }

        // overwrite form parameters
        loginRequest.form("email", "your-email-here", true);
        loginRequest.form("pass", "your-password-here", true);

        browser.sendRequest(loginRequest);
    }
});

// this is your personal page:
System.out.println(browser.getPage());
```

Answer (score 0):

Although this is not a programming question, let me try to answer :) **Jodd Http** is a http library that also allows you to emulate browser, in sense that it preserve session, so you can eg login to some site and continue sending requests within the same session.

Therefore, the question is not much relate to tools you are using (good choice btw:) but to how Facebook works. Since we are not using its API here, you must simply investigate by yourself. The best way to do so is to use a real browser and open developer tools (all browsers have it). Inside developer tools there is usually a tab named 'Net' where you can see all traffic between the browser and site. Just filter out non-html requests, to remove all those requests that loads images, scripts, css...

Now simply perform your steps in browser and watch what is being send. Then simply reply the same requests using **Jodd** :)

Here is an example of one such request for adding friends:

[image: facebook request example]

I've just reply the same request (for testing purposes) and, *voila*, 10 minutes later the test account got so many friends :)